# how to redirect the user to the same page that he is going to when 401 error appear?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, https, ionic2

I take this intercept function from angular5 documentation.
i catch the 401 error bass the request that return 401 i need to recall him or in another way refresh the page the he was going to it.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
      .do(
        event => {},
        err => {
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status == 401) {
            // handle 401 errors
            this._events.publish('error:401');
          }
        });
  }
```

I'm using anuglar5 and ionic2+ ...
i have this bunch of request made at the same time :

```
const userSubscription = Observable
      .forkJoin(
        ...[
          this._userProvider.currentUser$.skipWhile((user: UserOrAnonymous) => user._profileType === ProfileType.ANONYMOUS).take(1),
          this._lookupsProvider.lookups$.get(CONFIG.LOOKUPS.PROFILE_LOOKUP).take(1),
          this._lookupsProvider.lookups$.get(CONFIG.LOOKUPS.TAGS).take(1),
          this._Service.getEnrolledCoursesOfUser(),
          this._Service.getEnrolledWebinarsOfUser()
        ]
      )
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          this.userProfile = res[0];
          this._profileLookup = res[1];
          this._tagsLookUp = res[2];
          this.enrolledCoursesOfUser = res[3];
          this.enrolledWebinarsOfUser = res[4];
          if (this.userProfile['disabilityID']) {
            this.disabilityObject = this._profileLookup.disabilities.filter(
              (disability) => disability.id === this.userProfile['disabilityID']
            )[0];
          }
          ;
          this.contentIsLoaded = true;
          this.showForm = true;
        },
        () => {
          this.contentIsLoaded = true;
          this.showForm = false;
        });
    this._subscriptions.push(userSubscription);
```

when this forkjoin excutes,this function  this._ethraiService.getEnrolledCoursesOfUser(), return 401 because it needs token and the token's date expire, so the forkjoin will enter the unsuccessful function :

```
 this.contentIsLoaded = true;
              this.showForm = false;
```

so even if i autologin the page will never appear, it will appear a blank page because i saide this.showForm = false that hidden the form.

autologin event :

```
_events.subscribe('error:401',
      () => {
        this._loader = this._helperProvider.presentLoader();
        this._authService.getCredentials()
          .then(
            credentials => {
              if (credentials) {
                this._authService.logIn(JSON.parse(credentials))
                  .subscribe(
                    () => {
                      this._loader.dismiss();
                      console.log('auto login success');
                    },
                    () => {
                      this.nav.push(LoginPage);
                      this._loader.dismiss();
                    }
                  );
              }else{
                this._loader.dismiss();
                this.nav.push(LoginPage);
              }
            },
            () => {
              this._loader.dismiss();
              this.nav.push(LoginPage);
            }
          );
      })
```

the forkjoin function is in profile page that the user want to navigate to, but a 401 error happened so because forkjoin if it  has one failed request it will enter the failed function not the success function ,and the failure message hidden the form , what i need is to reload the profile page.

Comment: Where are you doing the auto login?

Comment: Will a page refresh handle this already? The problem is only when making a service call via `httpClient`?

Comment: @sabithpocker i addeh the function to the question

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve the current location inside the constructor of your interceptor like this:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
}
```

You can use `window.location.replace()` to redirect the user to the current URL like this:

```
window.location.replace(this.currentUrl)
```

Or simply use `window.location.reload()` to refresh the page.

Comment: I got this error when i inject Router:  Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ErrorInterceptor: ([object Object], ?).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply reload the page with

```
window.location.reload();
```

Or you can get the actual URL then navigate to the current route

```
constructor(private loc: Location, private router: Router) {
  console.log(loc.path());
  const fragments = loc.path().split('/');
  fragments.shift();
  router.navigate(...fragments);
}
```

Comment: the url doesn't denote to the location , and i have forkjoin that have many request one of them return 401 so the forkjoin access the unsuccess function that hide the form

Comment: Sorry, what ? I didn't understand what you said. And by "URL", I mean the Angular URL, the one after your domain name.

Comment: the url : http://....../gate/api/enrolledCoursesOfUser
doesn't denote to the location that what i mean

Comment: the URL returned by `loc.path()` isn't what you requested, it is the page the user is currently on. Seriously, before criticizing, maybe you should try.

Comment: i edit my question hope now you understand the problem

Comment: You didn't add any clarification on what you want, only how your calls work ... Look, you asked to redirect on the same page, I provided. You don't want to try this, then I am of no use anymore. Good luck with your issue !

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of passing the currentUrl to autoLogin function and going to that url once auto login is success, this is a rough idea:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req)
            .do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.status > 300) {
                } else {
                }
                return event;
            })
            .catch((err: any, caught) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (err.status === 401) {
                        const currentUrl = window.location.href;
                        this.autoLogin(currentUrl);
                    }
                    return Observable.throw(err);
                }
            });
    }

    autoLogin(redirectUrl: string): void {
        this._loader = this._helperProvider.presentLoader();
        this._authService.getCredentials()
          .then(
            credentials => {
              if (credentials) {
                this._authService.logIn(JSON.parse(credentials))
                  .subscribe(
                    () => {
                      this._loader.dismiss();
                      console.log('auto login success');
                      window.location.href = redirecttUrl; // reload the page from where autologin was requested
                    },
                    () => {
                      this.nav.push(LoginPage);
                      this._loader.dismiss();
                    }
                  );
              }else{
                this._loader.dismiss();
                this.nav.push(LoginPage);
              }
            },
            () => {
              this._loader.dismiss();
              this.nav.push(LoginPage);
            }
          );
      }
}
```